# Two columns to Point

Tags: sql, oracle, geometry

I have this kind of data.

[image]

These are LAT/LONG columns. Is there a possibility to convert them into SDO_POINT? Geometry column in oracle database?
Directly without changing the table, like SELECT SDO_PONT(X,Y).. etc.?

Answer (score 1):

You may use `SDO_POINT_TYPE` type constructor in `select` statement (`SYS_XMLGEN` is added just to print a value in db<>fiddle):

```
with tab(x,y) as (
  select level, dbms_random.value(1, 10)
  from dual
  connect by level < 5
)
select
  tab.*
  , SYS_XMLGEN(SDO_POINT_TYPE(x => x, y => y, z => 0)) as point_
from tab
```

| X | Y | POINT_ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9.35393779488900318396101093241885727099 | <?xml version="1.0"?> <ROW> <X>1</X> <Y>9.35393779488900318396101093241885727099</Y> <Z>0</Z> </ROW> |
| 2 | 1.66114260547662456962236114684188698629 | <?xml version="1.0"?> <ROW> <X>2</X> <Y>1.66114260547662456962236114684188698629</Y> <Z>0</Z> </ROW> |
| 3 | 8.12429295171479479718811137064961359487 | <?xml version="1.0"?> <ROW> <X>3</X> <Y>8.12429295171479479718811137064961359487</Y> <Z>0</Z> </ROW> |
| 4 | 6.63728725334717366406587955611669765791 | <?xml version="1.0"?> <ROW> <X>4</X> <Y>6.63728725334717366406587955611669765791</Y> <Z>0</Z> </ROW> |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1G_Rjj90)